# How to run insert parameterized value in table using SQL transformation in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I need to insert a table using parameterized values in SQL transformation in informatica.

For example:
Table A:
`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`

Parameters: `col1 = 123`, `col2="STG"`,`col3="ncpdp"`, `col4= (select count(*) from ncpdp)`

Insert Statement: `Insert into A (col1,col2,col3,col4) values (?col1?,?col2?,?col3?,?col4?(means result of the col4 query) );`

I need to run this insert statement using SQL transformation in informatica.

Will it work?

I tried the basic transformation with dummy source passed this query in SQL transformation as Query mode, but it's not executed properly from informatica code and I didn't get any error.  Kindly let me is there anything I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should define a source that has the actual data. Then do a lookup to get the count from ncpdp, combine the pipelines and send to target.

Otherwise a dummy source that will fetch one row. Next, use an `Expression Transformation` to set values for the needed columns. Do a lookup to get the count and connect everything to target.

In case of any issues share what you've done and the error you get.